# Product descriptions & titles are stored in which file in Magento?

Tags: ftp

So basically some tables in my ecommerce magento website are missing, and the whole website basically cannot load properly / 'empty'. I cannot access the admin panel, and when I put in forgot password/username, it says my email is not found. I'm fine with that since I haven't touched it for 2 years or so, and I am not using the website.

However now, I want to retrieve the product descriptions and titles, as I stored all the measurements and full descriptions of the products there. Is there a way I can grab all these infos from maybe the FTP side? or are they strictly in the magento admin page? Someone please advise on how I can retrieve them without loggin in to admin panel.

I found the pictures already located in the media folder, so I just need the descriptions now. Would be great if you can put detailed steps as I am in no way an expert in coding. Thank you for your help and time, appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the database, then you can query for what you need.

```
-- get entity type for products
SELECT entity_type_id FROM eav_entity_type WHERE entity_type_code = 'catalog_product';

-- get attribute IDs
SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'name' AND entity_type_id = [entity_type_id from above query];
SELECT attribute_id FROM eav_attribute WHERE attribute_code = 'description' AND entity_type_id = [entity_type_id from above query];

-- get titles
SELECT entity_id, VALUE FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE attribute_id = [attribute_id from name query];

-- get descriptions
SELECT entity_id, VALUE FROM catalog_product_entity_text WHERE attribute_id = [attribute_id from description query];
```

The last two queries will give you the data. Entity_id is the product ID.

Answer (score 0):

These are all stored in the database of your store.

**Descriptions are stored in: catalog_product_entity_text**

**Titles should be stored in catalog_product_entity_varchar**

If you cannot login try this:
Go to your cPanel > phpMyAdmin, select your Magento database, click the SQL tab and paste this query:

```
UPDATE admin_user SET password=CONCAT(MD5('newpass'), ':np') WHERE username='AdminUser';
```

Note: Be sure to change 'newpass' with your new password, and change 'AdminUser' to your Magento admin username

Execute the query by clicking the Go button and your password will be changed.